# Calling Java method that uses hash map as a parameter

Tags: java, android, methods, hashmap

I have a method in an android application:

```
public void changeImageView (HashMap<String,String> Detail)
```

I have been trying to call this method in the onCreate method in the same class.

I have tried:

```
changeImageView();
```

and

```
changeImageView(HashMap<String,String> Detail);
```

Both of which give me errors. The first gives me an error stating that the parameters are missing - understandable. But when I try the second version, I get an error saying "expression expected" with `HashMap<String,String>`.

I am probably missing something very obvious and have been unable to find anything online that can answer my question.

Comment: You need to provide a `HashMap<String,String>` object. You can create an empty hash map with `new HashMap<String,String>()`

Comment: Try `changeImageView(someMap);` where `someMap` is declared as `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: And being nothing but sincere, you need to go through a basic Java tutorial and/or read a good book on learning Java before continuing Android programming or you will be miserable.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much for your comments!

codeMagic: I am working through a few exercises from text books. I'm struggling slightly but getting there! Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an instance of `HashMap<String, String>`.

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

After its filling or other operations on the map, pass it as a parameter to your method.

```
changeImageView(map);
```

---

I would suggest you reading about [methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) on Oracle Tutorials.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer as soon as the 'time barrier' to accept lapses :)

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is a collection class available in java.util package.

A method changeImageView() here has a definition which takes a HashMap object of type [Generic Type : Google it to know more about it].

You need to create a HashMap object :

```
Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

You can add values to the above hashmap as given below :

```
map.add("key1","value1");
map.add("key2","value3");
```

**depending upon your requirements.**

Now you can pass this map object to the changeImageView() method as given below:

```
changeImageView(map)
```

Seems like you are a newbie to Java and OOP , please refer any Java basic tutorials . This will help you to build up your basic concepts.